# blank output returning by process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()

Tags: c#, process

I am writing a wrapper class for closure compiler and I am getting empty string by `process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()` I have written following code.

```
  public class ClosureCompiler
    {
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        string _commandpath;
        public ClosureCompiler(string commandpath)
        {
            _commandpath = commandpath;

            psi.FileName = "java.exe"; 

            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        }

        public string Compile(string sourcefile)
        {
            psi.Arguments = " -jar " + _commandpath + " --js " + sourcefile; // +" --js_output_file " + destinationfile + "";

            var process = Process.Start(psi);

            process.WaitForExit();
            return process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

but when I am running command from command line output showing on standard output.

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of the lines process.WaitForExit(); and process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
After WaitForExit completes, process.StandardOutput is already "dead".

Your code (method Compile) should go like this:

```
var process = Process.Start(psi);
string stdOutput = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
process.WaitForExit();
return stdOutput;
```

You can also register a delegate to receive output data with [Process.OutputDataReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx) event